# Slow appearance of questions

Tags: support

I posted a question on main site, then on Meta and it is taking measurable time (Several minutes) before it shows up in the questions?

Is this due to a literally brand spanking new site, maybe data replication, or somesuch?  Or running on a slower server?

I have not seen this behavior on Stack Exchange sites before.

Comment: To be fair, StackOverflow does this too. But you're right, I've never seen it on any of the non-trinity sites.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an artifact of it being a new site. When traffic is really low, the caching issues are especially obvious. This will work itself out shortly.

Comment: I suspected as such, but was looking for confirmation, thanks!